# Unable to Configure Log4j2 using java.util.Properties

Tags: properties, configuration, log4j2

I am unable to configure log4j2 with java.util.properties. I always get this message "tatusLogger No Log4j 2 configuration file found". Please see my logger class. I am reading the log4j2 properties from two files.

I will be attaching my code to this post.

```
package my.common.logger;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Properties;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Configuration;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationSource;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Configurator;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.properties.PropertiesConfigurationFactory;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.util.PropertiesUtil;

public class MyLogger {
    private static boolean configured = false;
    private static Logger logger;
    static {
        System.setProperty("log4j.configurationFactory",     "my.common.logger.JCFLog4JConfigurationFactory");
    }
    private static void readConfiguration() throws Exception {
        LoggerContext context = (LoggerContext) org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(false);
        Configuration configuration =  ConfigurationFactory.getInstance().getConfiguration(context, createConfigurationSource()); 
        configuration.start();
        Configurator.reconfigure(); 
        configured = true;
    }
    public static Logger getLogger(String className) {
        try {
            if (!configured) readConfiguration();           
            return org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(className);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } 
        return null;
    }
    private static ConfigurationSource createConfigurationSource()
    {   Properties p = new Properties();
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        InputStream in = null;
        try {
            p.putAll(<Read from File 1>);
            p.putAll(<Read from File 2>);
            p.store(out, null);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        in = new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray());
        ConfigurationSource configSrc = null;
        try {
            configSrc = new ConfigurationSource(in);
        }
        catch (IOException i)
        {
            i.printStackTrace();
        }
        return configSrc;
    }
}
```

Here is Config Factory Code:

```
package nj.aoc.ito.cmfw.common.logger;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Configuration;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationFactory;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationSource;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.properties.PropertiesConfigurationFactory;
public class MyLog4JConfigurationFactory extends ConfigurationFactory {
    public MyLog4JConfigurationFactory() {

    }
    @Override
    public Configuration getConfiguration(LoggerContext ctx, ConfigurationSource source) {

         PropertiesConfigurationFactory factory = new PropertiesConfigurationFactory();
         return factory.getConfiguration(ctx, source);
    }
    @Override
    protected String[] getSupportedTypes() {
        return new String[]{".properties", "*"};
    }

}
```

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Thanks
Nags

Comment: Have you tried to pass -Dlog4j.configuration={path to file} from command line? If works you can think to set into static context or via environment variable

Comment: Please improve your question. Although the class MyLogger has the System.setProperty in it there is no explanation for how it is called. It does not contain a main method so it can't be the beginning of the app and it is possible Log4j is being initialized elsewhere. You have also not explained why you have (improperly) created your own getLogger method.